# To show every sylow p-subgroup is normal in G

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose that $\phi$ is an automorphism of $G$ such that $\phi^3$ is the identity automorphism. Suppose further that $\phi(x)=x$ implies that $x=e$. Prove that for every prime $p$ which divides $o(G)$, the $p$-Sylow subgroup is normal in G.

Its an problem from Herstein, prob 19 in 2.12,2nd edition.I need some hint to solve this.Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a problem from a textbook, so presumably something in the corresponding chapter is relevant.

Comment: No idea how to proceed...some hint will be appreciated

Comment: This would be a tough result to prove from just the Sylow theorems.  What else do you have available?  Any results about fixed-point-free automorphisms on finite groups, for example?

Comment: I know under such conditions if $\phi^2$ is identity then G is an abelian group...Is there any general result ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not exactly an easy exercise! The proof outline below is from Burnside's book, "The Theory of Groups of Finite Order".

1. Show that $G = \{x^{-1}\phi(x) : x \in G \}$.
2. If $g$ and $\phi(g)$ are conjugate in $G$, then $g=1$. (Proof. Suppose $\phi(g) = h^{-1}gh$. By 1, $h = x^{-1}\phi(x)$ for some $x$, so $\phi(g) = \phi(x^{-1})xgx^{-1}\phi(x) \Rightarrow \phi(xgx^{-1})=xgx^{-1} \Rightarrow xgx^{-1}=1 \Rightarrow g=1$.)
3. $g\phi(g)\phi^2(g)=1$ for all $g \in G$. (Let $x = g\phi(g)\phi^2(g)$. Tthen $x$ and $\phi(x)$ are conjugate, so it follows from 2.)
4. Similarly $\phi^2(g)\phi(g)g = 1$, so $g$ and $\phi(g)$ commute for all $g \in G$.
5. Any two conjugate elements in $G$ commute. (Proof. Let $g,h \in G$. By 1, $h=x^{-1}\phi(x)$ for some $x \in G$. Now by 4, $xgx^{-1}$ commutes with $\phi(xgx^{-1})$, so $g$ commutes with $x^{-1}\phi(x)\phi(g)\phi(x^{-1})x = h\phi(g)h^{-1}$ So $\phi(g)$ commutes with $h^{-1}gh$ and similarly $\phi^2(g)$ commutes with $h^{-1}gh$, and hence, by 3, so does $g$.)
6. Now, if $p$ is a prime dividing $|G|$, and $g \in G$ has order $p$, then the conjugates of $g$ in $G$ generate a normal (abelian) subgroup $N$ of $G$ of order a power of $p$. Now the largest normal subgroup $O_p(G)$ of $G$ of order a power of $p$ is characteristic in $G$ and hence left invariant by $\phi$ so we can complete the proof by applying induction to $G/N$.

Comment: By some more work one can show that G is nilpotent

Comment: Being nilpotent is equivalent to all Sylow subgroups being normal.

Comment: @DerekHolt I tried working through the proof outline, but I encountered several problems and questions, specifically in step 6. 1. What is the motivation behind showing the elements of $G$ commute with their conjugates? 2. Why do the conjugates of $g$, $g$ of order a power of $p$, generate a subgroup $N$ with $|N| = p^{k}$ for some integer $k$? 3. Why is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ of order a power of $p$ characteristic in $G$, and why does it matter for the proof that it is invariant under $\phi$?

Comment: @sanguine 1. I don't understand the question. We prove Step 5 because it is used in Step 6. 2.  If two elements of order $p$ commute then their product also has order $p$ (or $1$), so a finite set of commuting elements of order $p$ generates a  finite $p$-group. 3. For $\phi \in {\rm Aut}(G)$, $\phi(O_p(G))$ is a normal $p$-subgroup of $G$ with the same order as $O_p(G)$, and so $\langle O_p(G),\phi(O_p(G))\rangle$ is a normal $p$-subgroup, and we must have $\phi(O_p(G))=O_p(G)$. We  apply induction to $G/O_p(G)$ rather than to $G/N$.

Comment: @DerekHolt In question 1, I meant to ask where in step 6 we use the fact that $g$ commutes with its conjugates. But now I see that you used this fact in generating $N$. I have one final question: What is the relation between $N$ and $O_{p}(G)$? Does the existence of $N$ somehow imply the existence of $O_{p}(G)$?

Comment: The existence of $N$ shows that $O_p(G)$ is nontrivial, so $|G/O_p(G)| < |G|$, and we can apply induction. (Although, to do that,  you still have to show that the hypotheses on $\phi$ are satisfied by the induced action of $\phi$ on $G/O_p(G)$.)